# Script delete line for xcode

Tags: xcode, applescript

I have some problem with the default script of xcode, here is my script to delete line :

```
on run
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke (ASCII character 29) using {command down}
        keystroke (ASCII character 8) using {command down}
        keystroke (ASCII character 8)
    end tell
end run
```

(command right ; command delete; delete)

The script work but, it do not delete the empty line when i use a keyboard shortcut ("command D" for me).

Please help me to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you press <kbd>Command ⌘ + D</kbd>, the script is executed and it presses the keys you've assigned. When the script tries to keydown backspace, you are still pressing the command key. So, it will actually press CMD+backspace.

Change the command key to option key in the shortcut. This way, you can delete the lines properly.

Comment: Can I escape the shortcut key command for the script please? I can change to ^D , but the control will be keep pressed.

Comment: @Kenzo The control key doesn't interfere in empty line deletion, so you can use it.

Comment: In xcode: control + keystroke (ASCII character 8) : delete the empty line and the last word of the previous line. I tried with key up command (or key up control) at the end, but it's not work

Comment: @Kenzo Yes, I didn't know that. It's an Xcode behavior. Option will do this too. I'm just curious know: why do you want to assign this shortcut? It's simple to press CMD+Delete and Delete.

Comment: there are some cool Eclipse shortcut I would like to have for xcode: "command + d" to delete a line (with its content), "alt+up/down" to move a line :)....